# Añadir lineas de contorno a un plot filled.contour

Tags: r

estoy intentando realizar un contour plot con la función filled.contour y me gustaría añadir líneas de contorno para remarcar los valores significativos ya que estoy representando valores de correlación.

[Aquí](https://ufile.io/vmnqc) está el fichero de entrada llamado *ts_months_max*

Este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
# Esta función matrix.axes la encontré en el siguiente enlace: https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/peter_cock/r/matrix_contour/
matrix.axes <- function(data) {
  x <- (1:dim(data)[1] - 1) / (dim(data)[1] - 1);
  axis(side=2, at=x, labels=rownames(data), las=2);
  x <- (1:dim(data)[2] - 1) / (dim(data)[2] - 1);
  axis(side=1, at=x, labels=colnames(data), las=1);
}


library(colorRamps)
library(gplots)
library(graphics)
library(RColorBrewer)

ts_months_max <- as.matrix(read.csv('./example.csv',sep='')
    col <- rev(brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "RdBu"))
           filled.contour(ts_months_max,plot.axes=matrix.axes(ts_months_max), main="Index 1",levels=seq(0,1,0.1),col = col)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando ejecuto la siguiente y última línea para contornear los valores > 0.5, sólo un contorno se genera y se desplaza hacia la zona de la legenda.

```
 contour(ts_months_max, level=0.5,add=T)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería cualquier ayuda al respecto.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casi lo tienes, solo un detalle: deberías usar `countour()` en el contexto de `plot.axes`. Lo que puedes hacer es:

```
filled.contour(ts_months_max, 
               col = col, 
               plot.axes={contour(ts_months_max,add=T);
                          matrix.axes(ts_months_max)
                        },
               main="Index 1",
               levels=seq(0,1,0.1))
```

Lo cual te generará los contornos de todos los `levels`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O bien especificar un vector `level` con los niveles en los que quieres ver el contorno:

```
filled.contour(ts_months_max, 
               col = col, 
               plot.axes={contour(ts_months_max,level = c(0.5,0.6,0.7), add=T);
                          matrix.axes(ts_months_max)
                        },
               main="Index 1",
               levels=seq(0,1,0.1))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Patricio Moracho, es justo lo que necesitaba. Investigaré un poquito más para darle un formato más personalizado al contorno. De nuevo muchas gracias.